# Dynamically add options to select select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a select drop down which is dynamically filled up with options, the options are the years, e.g. 2010, 2011, 2012

But with each coming year the webpage should add new entry in the drop down with the current year. The first entry of the year is 2010 fixed but the last entry is dynamic and depends on the current year..

Any help?

Comment: please add the code that you have tried so far and also http://jsfiddle.net if possible

Comment: i havent tried any code as of now, as im not coming up with any logic..

Comment: check the fiddle posted in my answer .. does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

for (var i = 2010; i <= currentYear; i++) {
  var selected = '';
  if (i == currentYear)
    selected = 'selected';
    
  $("#years").append("<option value='" + i + "'" + selected + ">" + i + "</option>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='years' />
```

Comment: i have dynamically counted the options for the drop down and they are with me in an integer array, now this integer array now have entries, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014. but next year it will have an entry of 2015 automatically, so i have that dynamic array ready with me, but now the question is how i shud go about adding the values of array to select options?

Comment: Can you use a loop similar to the above to go through the array and add each item to the select?

Comment: in this solution, how should i write the select tag in htmls, im clear with the jquery which operates on it, but the select tag itself? how shoud i write the years select tag?

Comment: See the first HTML part. You can have a select tag anywhere in your html with a proper ID. So something like <select id='years'/> in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you select the current year substract 2010 from it ( because it is a fix end) and then you will count up from 2010 adding the amount from your result?
Thats how I would do that with the first thoughts.

Edit:
If you fill the dropdown on each load of the page you always fill that array with the amount calculated from your substraction.
I don't get the problem.

Comment: im ready with the subtraction, but that doesnt end here, when the new year starts in 2015, there should be new entry in the select dropdown,  which should automatically get counted and be added to select dro down

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it .. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QcYL/3/)

```
 $("select").append("<option value='added'>added</option>");
```

append option according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/makla/6vRS4/) link (without jquery).

```
<form>
<select id="mySelect">
</select>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var to = new Date().getFullYear();
var option;
for (var i = 2010; i <= to; i++)
{
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;
    x.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the actual date :

```
 var startYear = 1950;
 var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

And then you can generate your select options

```
var select = '<select>';
for (var i = startYear; i <= currentYear; i++){
     select += '<option>'+i+'</option>';
}
select += </select>;
```

Comment: i have dynamically counted the options for the drop down and they are with me in an integer array, now this integer array now have entries, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014. but next year it will have an entry of 2015 automatically, so i have that dynamic array ready with me, but now the question is how i shud go about adding the values of array to select options?

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear(); 

for (var i=2010;i<year+1;i++) {
   $('#MySelect').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>')
}
```

[FiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/8R8fZ/1/)